# SQL stament to determine the number of Mondays in a month

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to get the number of Mondays in a given month (and year) without using T-SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without using T-SQL"? Do you mean using only ANSI SQL?

Comment: Is this question about SQL Server? What technology did you plan on using if you weren't going to use T-SQL?

Comment: Sorry, should have pointed out that I can use TSQL, but just didnt want to! I already have the SQL statement (running from VB.Net) and was hope just to add to it without having to write another function. It does look like I would have to write the function or use a pre generated table as stated by Andrew

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by saying:

> Is there a way to get the number of Mondays in a given month (and
>   year) **without using T-SQL?**

If you are hoping for a universal code fragment that will do this across all databases, forget it.  I doubt that you'll even be able to get a version to run on two different databases.  Dates and things like weekdays tend to be be implemented differently across database vendors.

Here is the TSQL way (Monday Month Count):

```
;with AllDates AS
(SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),GETDATE(),112)+'01') AS DateOf
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DateOf+1
 FROM AllDates
 WHERE
 MONTH(DateOf+1)=MONTH(CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),GETDATE(),112)+'01'))
)
SELECT COUNT(DateOf) AS MondayCountMonth
FROM AllDates 
WHERE DATENAME(weekday,DateOf)='Monday'
```

Here is the TSQL way (Monday Year Count):

```
;with AllDates AS
(SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(4),GETDATE(),112)+'0101') AS DateOf
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DateOf+1
 FROM AllDates
 WHERE
 YEAR(DateOf+1)=Year(CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(4),GETDATE(),112)+'0101'))
)
SELECT COUNT(DateOf) AS MondayCountYear
FROM AllDates 
WHERE DATENAME(weekday,DateOf)='Monday'
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 367)
```

**EDIT** based on OP comment, here is a version which finds the monthly and yearly Monday counts as sub-queries within another query:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(5))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,'aaa')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'bbb')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,'ccc')

;with MonthMondayCount AS
(SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),GETDATE(),112)+'01') AS DateOf
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DateOf+1
 FROM MonthMondayCount
 WHERE
 MONTH(DateOf+1)=MONTH(CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),GETDATE(),112)+'01'))
)
,YearMondayCount AS
(SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(4),GETDATE(),112)+'0101') AS DateOf
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DateOf+1
 FROM YearMondayCount
 WHERE
 YEAR(DateOf+1)=Year(CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(4),GETDATE(),112)+'0101'))
)
SELECT
    y.*
    ,(SELECT COUNT(DateOf) AS MondayCountMonth FROM MonthMondayCount WHERE DATENAME(weekday,DateOf)='Monday') AS MondayCountMonth
    ,(SELECT COUNT(DateOf) AS MondayCountYear FROM YearMondayCount WHERE DATENAME(weekday,DateOf)='Monday') AS MondayCountYear
    FROM @YourTable  y
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 367)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Col1        Col2  MondayCountMonth MondayCountYear
----------- ----- ---------------- ---------------
1           aaa   5                52
2           bbb   5                52
3           ccc   5                52

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: What I meant was I already have the SQL statement (which runs from VB) written, so If I could just add the subquery to get the Mondays, that would be great. And yes, it would have helped if I mentioned I am using MS SQL Server 2005!

Answer (score 2):

Try this : )

```
DECLARE @tmpDate as date
set @tmpDate  = getdate(); --you can add any date
DECLARE @Startdate as varchar( 8)
DECLARE @Enddate as varchar( 8)
SELECT @Startdate = replace(convert(varchar,cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @tmpDate), 0) as date) , 111), '/', '');
SELECT @Enddate =  replace(convert(varchar, cast(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@tmpDate)+1,0)) as date), 111), '/', '');

with [dates] as (
    select  convert(date , @Startdate  ) as [date] --start
    union all
    select   dateadd(day , 1 , [date]) 
    from [dates]
    where [date] < @Enddate )
Select X.WeekDayNumber, count(X.WeekDayNumber) as NumberOfDays
from (
SELECT [date] , DATEPART(weekday,[date] ) as WeekDayNumber
from [dates]
WHERE [date] IS NOT NULL)X
Group  by X.WeekDayNumber
option (maxrecursion 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( DATEADD( DAY, -1, DATEADD(  MONTH, 1 , month + '-01' ) -
  DATEADD( DAY, 7 - DATEPART( WEEKDAY, month + '-01' ), month + '-01' )
) DIV 7 + 1
```

I don't know how much ANSI SQL compatible this is but <strike>it works in MySql</strike> (not after the changes, it should work in SQL Server now).

`month` should be in `'yyyy-mm'` format

Comment: You nailed the part about not using T-SQL :).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson The only T-SQL statement here is DATEDIFF right? We can rewrite that by converting to timestamp and doing simple minus operation.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Actually I didn't even have to convert to timestamp, just the minus operation gives the same result (see the updated code), But I'm still not sure if this behavior is guaranteed in ANSI SQL.

Comment: Don't know about ANSI SQL but it will not work in SQL Server. But you still have my +1. It is of course possible to use this and convert it to SQL Server. I'm just not sure about what the OP means when he/she says "without using T-SQL".

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: alright, looks like we should use + sign instead of `CONCAT()` to make it work with SQL Server, corrected that too.

Comment: and changed `WEEKDAY()` to `DATEPART( WEEKDAY, )`, we don't even need the `IF()` anymore.

Comment: `INTERVAL` is not valid in SQL Server

Comment: Using `DATEADD()` now which is T-SQL, if you know any non-T-SQL alternative let me know.